# How to select data(with one decimal type) from a table and insert into another table (with different decimal type)

Tags: sql, sql-server, casting, typecasting-operator

I want to select data from TABLE A and insert data into TABLE B. Though I know how to achieve this. I have used:

```
INSERT INTO TableA(column1, column2, column3, ...)
SELECT column1, column2, column3, ...
FROM TableB
WHERE condition;
```

But the challenge is the data type. The target TABLE A has a column with data type definition as

```
column1(decimal(16,3),null)
```

Whereas the table TABLE B has a column with data type definition as

```
column1(decimal(15,4),null)
```

Please help me here!

Comment: I'm confused . . . I would called `A` the target table, not `B`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be fine.  SQL Server will automatically convert the values.  If you have a very large value in B that doesn't fit in A, then you could get an error.

To solve that, use `try_convert()`:

```
INSERT INTO TableA(column1, column2, column3, ...)
    SELECT TRY_CONVERT(decimal(15,4), column1), column2, column3, ...
    FROM TableB
    WHERE condition;
```

This will avoid a type conversion error.

Comment: Thank you so much for this solution. Can you recheck my question. I have made an update with the data types.

Comment: @ArpitaDutta . . . That really doesn't change the gist of the answer, which is to use `try_convert()` to explicitly convert to the correct type.